# jQuery Dropdown - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to create the jquery select field which includes images. (ddslick)

It seems that there is something wrong with with the `.js` file, as the console is showing an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ddslick'
but in works in jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/newbie123/zUgyd/5/

It loads correctly in jsfiddle, but gives that error in the console and doesn't load.

I have tried to also put this into the page's script, (using a script plugin on wordpress), which is:

```
//Dropdown plugin data
            var ddData = [
                {
                    text: "Facebook",
                    value: "FB",
                    description: "Description with Facebook",
                    imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
                },
                {
                    text: "Twitter",
                    value: "TWT",
                    description: "Description with Twitter",
                    imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
                },
                {
                    text: "LinkedIn",
                    value: "LI",
                    description: "Description with LinkedIn",
                    imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png"
                },
                {
                    text: "Foursquare",
                    value: "FSQ",
                    description: "Description with Foursquare",
                    imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png"
                }
            ]
```

HTML

```
<form id="quote" action="" method="get"><script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$('#quote').keyup(function (){   doTotal(this);   calcMenu(this); });
// ]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$('#myDropdown').ddslick({
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
        //callback function: do something with selectedData;
    }   
});</script>
<div id="myDropdown">
<select id="selectMenu">
        <option value="0" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Facebook">Facebook</option>
        <option value="1" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Twitter">Twitter</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/linkedin-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with LinkedIn">LinkedIn</option>
        <option value="3" data-imagesrc="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/foursquare-icon-32.png"
            data-description="Description with Foursquare">Foursquare</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
```

in `header.php`

```
  wp_head(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/jquery.ddslick.js"></script>
<!-- Make sure your CSS file is listed before jQuery -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: one gotchya i've dealt with: make sure you're not include that dropdown js twice. it will fire twice; opening and closing so fast that it looks like it's not working. i don't know if this is your issue but this bummed me out for awhile.

Comment: @Orolo - It seems to be only loading once. but when I checked, I noticed I have loaded 2 different versions of jquery - version 1.6. and 1.8... is this an issue?

Comment: could be. you probably don't want two versions loaded simultaneously for other reasons, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/jquery.ddslick.js"></script>
<!-- Make sure your CSS file is listed before jQuery -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

.js files are not CSS. :) Your jQuery plugin is included before jQuery. You should fix that.

Comment: thank you. what a silly mistake :/  The error in the console is now gone, but the select Dropdown is still now functioning?

Comment: Hard to guess without looking at the actual site :\ is it online by any chance so you can provide a link ?

Comment: You have two jQuery's included - 1.6.4 on line 25 and 1.8 on line 245 .. that's generally a recipe for pain.